# SuggestBox override addSelectionHandler

Tags: gwt

I have a custom Oracle with Objects to pass to the SuggestBox. Then I need get back a object when it's selected from de SuggestBox.

```
public HandlerRegistration addSelectionHandler(SelectionHandler<SuggestOracle.Suggestion> handler)
```

The problem is that I don't have Suggestion. I have "CustomSuggestion". I read de API and I try to write a Custom SuggestBox implementing the interface HasSelectionHandlers but I can't because the SuggestBox have a implementation of the interface. I get the error:

```
The interface HasSelectionHandlers cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: HasSelectionHandlers<SuggestOracle.Suggestion> and HasSelectionHandlers<CustomSuggestion>
```

Can you help me? Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem. Have a look at the following example (really basic but you should get an idea on how to deal with custom suggestions). Hope that helps:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    SuggestBox box = new SuggestBox(new CustomOracle<CustomSuggestion>());

    box.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<SuggestOracle.Suggestion>() {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Suggestion> event) {
            String value = ((CustomSuggestion) event.getSelectedItem()).fSomeOtherValue;
            Window.alert(value);
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(box);
}

private class CustomOracle<CustomSuggestion> extends SuggestOracle {

    private LinkedList<Starter.CustomSuggestion> fStore;

    public CustomOracle() {
        fStore = new LinkedList<Starter.CustomSuggestion>();
        fStore.add(new Starter.CustomSuggestion("2", "two", "foo"));
        fStore.add(new Starter.CustomSuggestion("22", "twenty-two", "bar"));
        fStore.add(new Starter.CustomSuggestion("222", "two-hundred twenty-two", "w000t"));
    }

    @Override
    public void requestSuggestions(Request request, Callback callback) {
        String query = request.getQuery();
        LinkedList<Starter.CustomSuggestion> result = new LinkedList<Starter.CustomSuggestion>();
        for (Starter.CustomSuggestion entry : fStore) {
            if (entry.fDisplay.contains(query)) {
                result.add(entry);
            }
        }
        callback.onSuggestionsReady(request, new Response(result));
    }

}

private class CustomSuggestion implements Suggestion {

    private String fReplace;
    private String fDisplay;
    private String fSomeOtherValue;

    public CustomSuggestion(String display, String replace, String someOtherValue) {
        fDisplay = display;
        fReplace = replace;
        fSomeOtherValue = someOtherValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString() {
        return fDisplay;
    }

    @Override
    public String getReplacementString() {
        return fReplace;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I was determined to do without cast but I change it and now work. Thanks.
String value = ((CustomSuggestion) event.getSelectedItem()).fSomeOtherValue;

Comment: It says in the javadoc to "downcast the `Suggestion` object to the subinterface". Guess it's intended then.